# how to get the process time for a particular process using process.Totalprocessortime

Tags: c#

i am using process.Total processortime to get the processor time for that particular process. But most of the time i get a value '0'.how can i solve it,is any other method to get the process time for a process

Comment: I cant say I have experienced that, but perhaps it is a 'resetting' counter (iow when you read it, it resets to 0).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx This value is the sum of the UserProcessorTime and the PrivilegedProcessorTime, where the former is a TimeSpan that indicates the amount of time that the associated process has spent running code inside the application portion of the process (not inside the operating system core) and the latter is a  TimeSpan that indicates the amount of time that the process has spent running code inside the operating system core.

Having said that, what does your process do? If it's running a thread that just sits and waits for some event then I don't think you will get a number much different from 0. But if it's actually crunching something and you are still getting 0 then the question is probably, how do you get the process instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 readings if you going to calculate the % processor time for the process. TotalProcessorTimeTaken is just the time the reading was taken (DateTime.Now). Use the formulae below:

```
double res = (((p.TotalProcessorTime - prev.TotalProcessorTime).TotalMilliseconds /
 (p.TotalProcessorTimeTaken - prev.TotalProcessorTimeTaken).TotalMilliseconds) * 100) /
                        taskManagerResponse.ProcessorCount;
```